# jsPDF gerando pdf gigante

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf

Estou utilizando o jsPDF para gerar um PDF a partir de um componente, porém, ao clicar em 'gerar', a informação no PDF resultante aparece com tamanho excessivamente grande. O que pode estar causando esse problema?

```
download(): any {
  const pdf = new jsPDF({
    orientation: 'portrait',
    unit: 'mm',
    format: 'a4'
  });

  pdf.html(this.toPrint.nativeElement, {
    callback: (pdf) => {
      pdf.save("teste.pdf")
    }
  });
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="modal-body" id="container" #toPrint>
  <app-apresentacao-resumo></app-apresentacao-resumo>
</div>
```